How to shift the view to the central coordinates of an addRasterImage()?
I use addRasterImage() to display an image within a group that is later selected through addLayersControl(). The initial setView() is defined for a relatively large region, which is not centered on my small satellite image.
This example is close to what I have:
library(RStoolbox) #for the example satellite image
library(terra)
library(leaflet)
B4  <- project(rast(system.file("external/landsat/LT52240631988227CUB02_B4.TIF", package="RStoolbox")), "EPSG:4326")
ext(B4)
leaflet() %>% 
  setView(lng = -50.5, lat=-3.4 , zoom = 9) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Satview") %>%
  addRasterImage(B4, group = "Landsat") %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    #baseGroups = c("Satview","OSM","r1","a"),
    baseGroups = c("Satview","Landsat"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE, autoZIndex = TRUE))

Desired behavior:
As addRasterImage() is intended for relatively small images such as mine, I would like the display to shift to the center of the image once its group ("Landsat" in this example) is selected in the menu.
Is there a way to achieve this? I do not see an option within addRasterImage() and do not see how to repeat setView() for a given group.

Please have ar read. You are much more likely to receive some effort from others if you put yourself some effort in asking a great, reproducible, and thereby minimal question.

I have edited the question including a reproducible example.

You can add some JS here (see Custom JavaScript with htmlwidgets::onRender() in the leaflet docs) which attaches a baselayerchange event to your map. This event checks whether one has chosen Landsat and if so, setView is invoked where lng and lat are defined by the center of the image. The coordinates are previously calculated from the SpatExtent.
library(RStoolbox)
library(terra)
library(leaflet)

B4 <- project(
  rast(
    system.file("external/landsat/LT52240631988227CUB02_B4.TIF", 
                package = "RStoolbox")
  ), "EPSG:4326")

vars <- ext(B4) |> as.list()

lngCenter <- (vars$xmax - vars$xmin) / 2 + vars$xmin
latCenter <- (vars$ymax - vars$ymin) / 2 + vars$ymin

leaflet() |>
  setView(lng = -50.5,
          lat = -3.4,
          zoom = 9) |>
  addTiles() |>
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "Satview") |>
  addRasterImage(B4, group = "Landsat") |>
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("Satview", "Landsat"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE, autoZIndex = TRUE)
  ) |>
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    sprintf(
      "function(el, x) {
         var map = this;
         map.on('baselayerchange', function(e) {
           if (e.name === 'Landsat') {
             map.setView([%s, %s], 12)
           }
         });
       }",
      latCenter,
      lngCenter
    )
  )



Yes, sorry I had not seen your answer. I had replied to a similar solution in https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/931.

Anyway, after trying, I am finally not using this tool in my map: Having a "zoom to layer" behavior always active (anytime the layer is selected) is often inconvenient. For example, if we want to display Satview for the zone of interest once we have selected Landsat, the Satview button brings us back to the initial view. We would need a second button next to the one selecting the layer so that the user can "zoom to layer" if needed, but not always.
